# Fastest way to fetch multiple documents from Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a SQL API Cosmos DB collection with the id and partition key both equal to `/id`.

Given a list of IDs, I need to fetch all those documents. When using the .NET SDK (v3.25), which of the below Container class methods is recommended to get the lowest latency:

1. In parallel, use `ReadItemAsync` to read all documents.
2. Use `ReadManyItemsAsync` to read all the documents.
3. Use `GetItemQueryIterator` with a SQL query of the form `SELECT * FROM c where c.id in ('id-1', 'id-2', ...)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to retrieve large group of individual items, the most efficient way is to use **ReadManyItemsAsync()** rather than invoking **ReadItemAsync()** many times/Parallel.